# where does Xcode start building from?

Tags: xcode

i have just started on iOS programming and was just wondering where does Xcode start to build from? does it start from 'viewcontroller.m' and eventually out to other implementation files?

Comment: It builds all the files marked to be in the executable.  Open the "file explorer" window on the right side and click on an executable file in the "navigator" window.  On the right side you will see check boxes indicating what files are part of the executable.  By default this is all .m files.

Answer (score 1):

It builds them in the order they show up in the compile sources phase of your target. You can view it by clicking on your Project in the Project Navigator pane (the folder icon on the right side of the main window), then selecting the target you are currently building. From there, click on the "Build Phases" tab and open up the group named "Compile Sources". Your files will be listed in the order they will be compiled.